# How to get the item before the last iteration in the loop of a Smarty array

Tags: smarty

Hello smart(y) Girls and Guys!

Unfortunately I can't find an answer and of course I am new to Smarty.... Hope you can helo me out!

I am looking for the item before the last item of a smarty foreach loop. So e.g if my array has 8 iterations i need the 7th iteration, if there are 3 iterations, I need the 2nd ... and so on.

How can I get it? I can get the .last one, but how to get the one before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "{foreach} properties": @index, @iteration, @first, @last, @show, @total.
Example for your case:

```
{foreach $array as $a}
  {if $a@iteration == $a@total-1}
  last-1 value is: $a
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```